# How to return an array of json objects instead of just consecutive json objects?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I'm having a little problem here with this simple code,

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "contacts";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo("connection failed");
}
else {
$sql = "select * from info" ;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$response=  array( 'name'=> $row['name'] , 'email'=> $row['email']   );
echo json_encode($response);
}   
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

It's giving me an output like this

```
{"name":"someone","email":"someone@gmail.com"} 
{"name":"someone.else","email":"some@email.com"}
```

instead i want an array of json objects like this,

```
[
{"name":"someone",
 "email":"someone@gmail.com"} 

,{"name":"someone.else",
 "email":"some@email.com"}
]
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$response = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // Collect your data to array
    $response[] =  array( 'name'=> $row['name'] , 'email'=> $row['email']   );
}  

// echo and json_encode ONCE after your while-loop
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: That was it, Thank you!

Comment: Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` for it to be interpreted as JSON automatically (like jQuery for example)